# Xcode - add a new file - don't go in in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, viewcontroller

Strange bug here.

Starting to learn Swift and so Xcode.

I want to add a new view to my project so I a new viewController into the storyboard. To handle it I do Super+N to add a new file > Cocoa Touch Class >>> Path (but in option I cannot select a target like I saw in some tutorials) > Create.
The file won't go to my project folder in the Xcode file's tree. Instead it goes at the top of it like a totally separate file.

In the identity inspector of the new viewController if I select the Assistant Editor it won't show me the new swift file but UIViewController.h.

I'm block here and cannot continue my project.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you drag a new view controller to the storyboard it comes with its own associated full-screen UIView, which you then want to "subclass" and customize. That's what you're doing with your attempt to add a new 'Cocoa Touch Class'.After you click the "Next" button you are than asked to provide a name for your subclass. Make sure that you're specifying it to be a UIView subclass. Then, when you click the button and move onto the next page of the dialog, make sure that you put the the newly created files (both .m and .h files will be created) in the proper location in your folder hierarchy. Sounds like you may not have done this and so your files got put somewhere else where you didn't expect.

Comment: 1) Yes it comes with it own UIView.

Comment: OK, then just what you need to do next is to create .m and .h files for a new UIView subclass which you will provide the name for so that you can customize this UIView.

Comment: (sorry I past the 5min to edit my comment)
2) Yes I select UIView subclass
3) I don't have .m/.h files bc I doing a swift project and I select the good path of my project to into.
4) I add <MyFile> to the fiel Class into Custom Class the Assistant Editor

Comment: OK, I don't understand why there's a UIViewController.h file, then. Make sure that you're specifying Swift, not Objective-C, in all of the dialogue windows that come up.

Comment: it's the file attach by default as UIViewController.
I made you a .zip file with some screenshot to show you what I do.
https://mega.co.nz/#!zgB3RBRJ!yfIDw-X0ypWiHVkdI3NEpwT4CCKRHFqBCV_pcfjxZFw

Answer (score 0):

Really strange, I am facing same issue with Xcode version(10.2). What i did to resolve this is reinstall the Xcode. This works for me.